# how to override key.serializer in kafka connect jdbc

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am doing mysql to kafka connection using kafka jdbc source connector. Everything working fine. Now i need to pass key.serializer and value.serializer to encrypt data as show at [macronova](https://github.com/macronova/kafka-serde-ext). but i didn't found any changes in output.

**POST API to start source connector**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name": "jdbc-source-connector-2",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
    "value.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
    "tasks.max": 10,
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/connect_test?user=roo&password=roo",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "table.whitelist" : "test",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "timestamp.column.name": "modified",
    "topic.prefix": "table-",
    "poll.interval.ms": 1000
  }
}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connectors take Converters only, not serializers via key and value properties

If you want to encrypt a whole string, you'd need to implement your own converter or edit your code that writes into the database to write into Kafka instead, then consume and write to the database as well as other downstream systems